# R data.table set specific columns to their last values, by group

Tags: r, data.table

Data looks like this:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Group
1       1       2       1
1       1       3       1
2       2       4       1
2       3       3       2
2       3       4       2
2       4       5       2
3       4       6       2
```

I want to set `Col1` and `Col3` to their LAST value, within `Group`
For instance, the last value of Col1 Group 2 is **3**. So in Group 2, I want all values of Col1 to be set to **3**.

Expected result:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Group
2       1       4       1
2       1       4       1
2       2       4       1
3       3       6       2
3       3       6       2
3       4       6       2
3       4       6       2
```

How can this be done with data.table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse`.  We group by 'Group', and use `mutate_at` to select the variable of interest, replace with the `last` value of each of the columns

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Col1, Col3), last)
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   Group [2]
#   Col1  Col2  Col3 Group
#  <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     2     1     4     1
#2     2     1     4     1
#3     2     2     4     1
#4     3     3     6     2
#5     3     3     6     2
#6     3     4     6     2
#7     3     4     6     2
```

---

Or with `data.table`, use the same logic, (if it is not a data.table, convert to data.table with `setDT`), specify the columns of interst in `.SDcols`, loop through the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`), get the `last` value and assign (`:=`) it to the columns

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- c("Col1", "Col3")
setDT(df1)[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, last), by = Group, .SDcols = nm1]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), Col2 = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), Col3 = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), 
    Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)

cols <- c("Col1", "Col3")
DT[, (cols) := .SD[.N], by = Group, .SDcols = cols][]
#    Col1 Col2 Col3 Group
# 1:    2    1    4     1
# 2:    2    1    4     1
# 3:    2    2    4     1
# 4:    3    3    6     2
# 5:    3    3    6     2
# 6:    3    4    6     2
# 7:    3    4    6     2
```

*Data*

```
DT <- fread("Col1    Col2    Col3    Group
1       1       2       1
1       1       3       1
2       2       4       1
2       3       3       2
2       3       4       2
2       4       5       2
3       4       6       2")
```